# Onchange event fire in dropdown and get value in controller of codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I need some help in ajax when `onchange` event fire in dropdown I want the value in controller but I did not get it.

Here is my view code:

VIEW:

```
<select name="user_role" id="user_role" onchange="calculate(this)">
    <option>--Select User--</option>  

    <?php foreach ($roll_get as $roll) { ?>

    <option value="<?php echo $roll->user_id; ?>" id="<?php echo $roll->user_id; ?>">
        <?php echo $roll->full_name; ?>
    </option>

    <?php } ?>

</select><br>
```

Below is my AJAX code:

```
function calculate(id)
{
    var id=id;

    $.ajax({  
        type:'POST',
        url:'welcome/user_manager',
        data:{'id':id},
        success:function(data){}
    });
}
```

This is my CONTROLLER:

```
public function user_manager() {
    $id=$this->input->post('id',true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Your js `calculate` method  should be like this :*

```
function calculate(obj) 
  {
    var id = $(obj).val();
    console.log(id);
    $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:"<?php echo site_url('welcome/user_manager');?>",
            data:{'id':id},
            success:function(data){
            }
        });
  }
```

Controller's `user_manager` method should be like this :

```
public function user_manager() 
{
   $id = $this->input->post('id',true);
   echo $id;
   exit;
}
```

Comment: Hello Mr @pradeep i got id in ajax but i stll did not get id in contrller..
Can you Please help me

Comment: make sure your path is correct and do it like this `print_r($this->input->post());die;` see network tab for output